# Passing unit8 to pcl::Passthrough

Tags: ros, point-cloud-library

I have a customized `PointXYZB` with fields `x`, `y`, `z`, and `beam` in `pcl`. `x`, `y`, `z` are float and `beam` is unit8 with either value equals to 0 or 1. I have registered my customized `PointXYZB` to pcl, and I'm trying to use `setFilterFieldName` to filter my point cloud in terms of field `beam`. The following is my code. The code compiles successfully but fails to filter out the correct result based on `beam`. I know we can use `setNegative` as a workaround but I want to know why my code fails. I guess there is something wrong when casting from uint8 to double in c++ API.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/filters/passthrough.h>
    
pcl::PointCloud<PointXYZB> filter (double lower, double upper)
    {
      pcl::PointCloud<PointXYZB>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<PointXYZB>);
      pcl::PointCloud<PointXYZB>::Ptr cloud_filtered (new pcl::PointCloud<PointXYZB>);
    

      // Create the filtering object
      pcl::PassThrough<PointXYZB> pass;
      pass.setInputCloud (cloud);
      pass.setFilterFieldName ("beam");
      pass.setFilterLimits (lower, double);
      pass.filter (*cloud_filtered);
      return *cloud_filtered;

    }

int main() {
  pcl::PointCloud<PointXYZB> f = filter(0.0, 0.0);
  pcl::PointCloud<PointXYZB> b = filter(1.0, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `(-0.1, 0.1)` and `(0.9, 1.1)` as limits instead?

Comment: @IBitMyBytes Yes. I tried different intervals but the filtration is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked, `PassThrough` only works for fields of type float: https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/filters/include/pcl/filters/impl/passthrough.hpp#L101

You can try [ConditionalRemoval](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/classpcl_1_1_conditional_removal.html) or, if your PCL version is sufficiently recent, [FunctorFilter/FunctionFilter](https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/master/function_filter.html)